# How to refresh data in table using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm new to ajax. I just want to simply view my table from the database using ajax. I have 2 files listbarang.html and showlist.php.

Here's my code

PHP (showlist.php)

```
<?php 
$link = @mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","projekpweb");
if($link->connect_errno)
{
    echo "Failed to connect. " . $link->connect_error;
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `barang`";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if(!$result)
{
    die("SQL GAK KONEK : " . mysqli_error($link));
}

echo "<table>
            <tr>
                <th>idbarang</th>
                <th>nama</th>
                <th>harga</th>
                <th>ekstensi_gambar</th>
            </tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "  <tr>
                <td>".$row["idbarang"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["nama"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["harga"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["ekstensi_gambar"]."</td>
            </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";    ?>
```

HTML (listbarang.html)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>LIST BARANG</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showList()
        {
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
                {
                    document.getElementById("tblList").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","showlist.php",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tblList">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            showlist();
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I wonder why the #tblList doesnt have the content of the the table.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you get for responseText? Log it to console!

Comment: please don't use @ to supress  messages ...

Comment: do you ever hit the `status===200`?

Comment: @Jeff I try to move document.getElementById("tblList").innerHTML = this.responseText; outside the "if" and it still doesnt work. I try to run showlist.php and it works perfectly, the data show up.

Comment: yeah, that won't work. write this inside the if: `console.log(this.responseText);` and see what you get in console.

Comment: @Jeff hmm nothing is in the this.responseText. But when I try to run showlist.php and it works perfectly, the data show up.

Comment: @Jeff oh i get it. it should be <div id="tblList"></div><script>showList();</script>

Comment: have a look at the network-tab (have that open before you reload listbarang.html) and see if what status codes you get there. maybe he doesn't find the script? maybe a cross-scripting error? (do you load the html via file::// maybe?)